# Using the Datastore API to Request Entities Through JSON

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I was wondering if anyone had experience with using the Datastore API through authorized JSON requests? I'm looking at the documentation here:

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/datasets/runQuery#try-it

...and honestly, the request body is a whole lot of 'what is going on here'.

I'm simply trying to make a query. Is there no way to request say, every `Section` entity in my database? Its so confusing :S

Comment: What do you have so far? Which programming-language you're using would be a good start :)

Comment: If you're using PHP, then try my php-gds library which simplifies access to the JSON API. https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds

Comment: Whoa, sorry I updated my tags. Python is the language!